# javascript parse regex string after before certain diameters

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello need some help right to parse out some values from this string, I've no luck getting the values I need.

```
string 1 = Binder stuck in CCH Axcess Pre Porting|  Domain: CBA-01 |  Due Date: 07-Jul-2022 |  Binder ID: 12345679
```

```
String 2 = Binder stuck in CCH Axcess Pre Porting|  Domain: ABC-01 |  Binder ID: 12345678
```

What I'm trying to get from these strings are the following

1. I was a section of the word in until the next | then I need everything after Domain: until the next | and same thing for Binder ID: I need everything until the end of the string.

I would expect the following:

```
["CCH Axcess Pre Porting", "ABC-01", "12345678"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with `split` but I read that is just an excuse for not using RegExp, so let's try:

```js
var str = "Binder stuck in CCH Axcess Pre Porting|  Domain: CBA-01 |  Due Date: 07-Jul-2022 |  Binder ID: 12345679";

var reg = /Binder stuck in\s+(.*?)\s*\|.+Domain:\s*(.*?)\s*\|.+Binder ID:\s*(.*?)\s*$/
var arr = str.match(reg);
arr.shift();
console.log(arr)
```